# Interior of connected metric spaces are connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

> Let $X$ a connected metric space. Is $int X$ connected?

I have a proposition that says: *if $X\subseteq Y\subseteq \overline{X}$ and $X$ is connected then $Y$ is connected*. But I'm having some problems with using this result. Because every set is open in itself we would have $X = intX \subseteq\overline{X}$ then $intX$ would be connected. Is this correct? What if $X$ is a connected subset of a (not necessarely connected) metric space?

Comment: What is $int X$ when $X$ is a metric space?

Comment: And what is $\bar{X}$ when $X$ is a metric space?

Comment: Are you sure $X$ is not a connected subset of a metric space? Otherwise, $X$ is closed so it is its own closure and $X$ is open so it is its own interior.

Comment: @JohnDouma I stated the question as it was proposed to me. I don't really know for sure.

Comment: @xyzzyz please see my comment on Maurizio Moreschi's answer

Comment: @mfl please see my comment on Maurizio Moreschi's answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative. Consider two full closed disks touching in one point in the euclidean plane, with induced topology. If you take the interior, you get the disjoint union of two open disks, which is not connected anymore.

Comment: Not in the induced topology, surely? In the ambient topology, i.e. that of the plane, yes.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you're trying to say, can you rephrase?

Comment: It's much the same point as was made in several comments on the question. I assume you mean the topology induced on the union of the touching discs by considering it as a subset of the plane (with its usual topology). But any space (whether or not it has been defined as a subset of another space) is open - and is therefore its own interior - in any topology that is defined on it.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! I assumed the interior was taken in some ambient space, otherwise the question would not be very interesting...

Comment: Indeed! It is a strange question, and I wonder where it came from.

Comment: It just needs to be edited to fix the formulation. I don't have the reputation to do so though.

Comment: But only the OP is in a position to edit the question-within-a-question. ("Let $X$ a connected metric space. Is $\operatorname{}int X$ connected?") That's the one that's strange. The OP's question itself is not strange. (I think I may be confusing myself now! - and the system is shushing us.)

Comment: The question in the yellow box is as it was proposed to me in a recent exam, so I'm also not sure about the formulation. But if $X$ is indeed the ambient space, my answer is right?

Comment: But I learned that connectedness is a property inherent of the set, so I imagined that the ambient space shoudn't be a concern.

Comment: Yes connectedness is intrinsic, there is no problem in there. The problem is just that you want to take the interior of a set, which is meaningful only if you are working in an ambient space (because in its very topology, every space is open by definition).

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi I just expected that the answer woundn't depend on the fact that $X$ is (or isn't) a subset of another set.